# TypeError: req.flash is not a function -- (NodeJs) (connect-flash) -- I can not open the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session, connect-flash

When I tried to log in from page, I got error

> TypeError: req.flash is not a function

**I explain the errors I got and the methods I tried**

1. **If I delete this code `console.log (req.flash ("validation_error"))` code in the function named "registerFormunuGoster" in the
   auth_controller file, I can make a successful link to the page in
   the first step. If I do not delete this code, I cannot connect to
   the page successfully in the first step.**
2. The text I mentioned above is translated into code below.
3. `const registerFormunuGoster = (req, res) => { res.render("register", { layout: "./layout/auth_layout" ,}) }`
4. Let's say I  write the code mentioned above and opened the page, after that I fill the form on my page and I get the same error whenever I press the submit button after filling out the form. To solve this problem, under the auth_controller.js file If I delete the code "req.flash (" validation_error ", errors)" in the function named "register" this time i get a different error.I am leaving the other error I get below. I think the reason I got such an error must be because I did res.redirect().
5. Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
6. The events I mentioned in item 4 are translated into code below.
7. `const register = (req, res) => {
   const hatalar = validationResult(req);

   ```
    if (!hatalar.isEmpty()) {
        res.redirect("/register")
    }
    res.render("register", { layout: "./layout/auth_layout" ,})
   ```

   }`

*Below are my app.js and auth_controller.js configuration*

app.js

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config()
const session = require("express-session")
const flash = require("connect-flash")
// database bağlantısı - veritabanı bağlantısı 
require("./src/config/database")

// TEMPALTE ENGİNE AYARALARI 
const ejs = require("ejs")
const expressLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts")
const path = require("path")
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.set("views", path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/views"))
app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(expressLayouts)


// routerlar include edilip kullanılır 
const authRouter = require("./src/routers/auth_router")
app.use("/", authRouter)


// formdan yollanılan verileri json a çevirip verilere dönüşmesi için bu şart
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))


//* const session = require("express-session")
//* Seesion ve flash message
//* bunları yapmak için yukarıdaki modul lazım
//? önemli bir not çıldıurmak üzereydim kodlar çalışmıyordu kodların çalışması üçün üst sıralar çekince oldu bakalım neyden kaynaklanıyorumuş deneyerek bulucam 
//? app.get gibi sunucu istekleri yönlendirmeden önce kullanılması lazımmış
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge:1000*5
    }
    //* maxAge: verilen cookienin ne kadar zaman sonra kendisini ihma etmesini söylüyor
    //* saniye cinsinden verdik 
}))
//? flash mesajlarının middleware olarak kullanılmasını sağladık yani aldığımız hatayı flash sayesinde kullanabilceğiz
app.use(flash())


let sayac = 0
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    if (!req.session.sayac) {
        req.session.sayac = 1
    } else {
        req.session.sayac++
    }
    res.json({ message: "Hello World", sayac: req.session.sayac })
})



app.listen(process.env.PORT, _ => console.log(`Server started at ${process.env.PORT} port `))
```

auth_controller.js:

```
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator")

const loginFormunuGoster = (req, res) => {
    res.render("login", { layout: "./layout/auth_layout" })
}
const login = (req, res) => {
    res.render("login", { layout: "./layout/auth_layout" })
}



const registerFormunuGoster = (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.flash("validation_error"))
    res.render("register", { layout: "./layout/auth_layout" ,})
}
const register = (req, res) => {
    const hatalar = validationResult(req);

// req.body adı altında girilen veriler gözüküyor
// console.log(req.body) 
// console.log(hatalar)
    if (!hatalar.isEmpty()) {
        // req.flash("validation_error",hatalar)
        res.redirect("/register")
    }
    res.render("register", { layout: "./layout/auth_layout" ,})
}


const forgetPasswordFormunuGoster = (req, res) => {
    res.render("forget_password", { layout: "./layout/auth_layout" })
}
const forgetPassword = (req, res) => {
    res.render("forget_password", { layout: "./layout/auth_layout" })
}


module.exports = {
    loginFormunuGoster,
    registerFormunuGoster,
    forgetPasswordFormunuGoster,
    register,
    login,
    forgetPassword,
}
```

**I would really appreciate everyone's help!!!**
**I hope I explained the error I received well**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem come from a misunderstanding of how you should send you request back.

The second error you have 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' indicates that the request you are trying to manipulate again is already finished (you can read a better explanation here: [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client))

So in your case, you cannot do a `.redirect` and a `.render` in the same request.

For your initial error, it seems that flash is not attached to the `req` object. I'm not sure but it might be because you are requiring it after your router and it is not ready when used in it.
There:

```js
// 'use' it before you require your auth_router
app.use(flash());

// then require your auth_controller.js file somewhere in this
const authRouter = require("./src/routers/auth_router")
app.use("/", authRouter)
```

Read connect-flash doc for more indication on how to use it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash

Comment: actually I worked 1-2 days to solve this problem and I read the documentation and watched the videos but it never came to my mind, thank you very much.I am very grateful.

Comment: I need your opinion on something more. Is there any part you say is missing in the question I asked?